# How do I remember (using shared preferences) ,items in my static array ?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-preferences, android-checkbox

I have a static array in my code and I am trying to remember the checks on them (only 1 is checkable at a time). Say I have items 1 ,2 ,3 and 4 and 3 is checked (1 2 4 will be unchecked) and if i click done button and return to the view later I would like to see 3 checked from last time. Is there a way I CAN DO THIS?
here's my code :

```
public static final  String[] groups = new String[] { "A", "B", "C", "D" };

    public static final  String[][] children = new String[][]  {
            { "1" } ,
            { "2" },
            { "3"},
            { "4" }
    };  

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dead, container, false);

        categoriesList1 =  (ExpandableListView)view.findViewById(R.id.categories);      

        String currTemplate = MainFragment.Default;
        for(@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") Map.Entry entry: map.entrySet()){
            if(mTemplateId.equals(entry.getValue())){
                currTemplate = (String) entry.getKey();
                break; 
            }
        }

        mAdapter = new MenuExpandableListAdapter(Fragment.groups, 
  MainFragment.children, currTemplate,  this.getActivity());
        mAdapter.setSelectionListner(this);
        categoriesList1.setGroupIndicator(null);
        categoriesList1.setChildIndicator(null);
        categoriesList1.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        categoriesList1.setOnChildClickListener(mAdapter);  
        return view;
    @Override
    public void onClick(final View view) {
        MainActivity activity = (MainActivity) getActivity();
        switch (view.getId()) {

            case R.id.button_done:
                saveUserPreferences();
                activity.hideSoftKeyboard(getView());
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You should read this to learn more about the basics of data storage, it's actually really easy :

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref

> You can use SharedPreferences to save any primitive data: booleans, floats, ints, longs, and strings. This data will persist across user sessions (even if your application is killed).

Comment: I have done this for other kid of data but never for static arrays, any example similar to mine  would help

Comment: You said you wanted one checkbox clicked at a time right? Save the index of the checkbox in sharedprefs and thats it dont worry about saving the array :P

Comment: any example will help? I am able to check the textboxes already. I just need to save them. I have created an operation variable to select the index : operationvar.setIndex(iSelected);

Answer (score 0):

you should generate another array containing only the checked choices , and save it (by shared data or singleton class). 
than when you are showing this Activity you put this values checked. so of course if this activity is opened for the first time, your checked items array will be null, so all the values would be unchecked.

to check by java , you can try this :

```
// also check this lines in the above example
ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
 holder.checkbox.setChecked(list.get(position).isSelected());
```

Comment: I am super confused now. I just wanted a simpler approach with shared prefs.I already set index of my variable with iSelected. how do i retrieve that with shared prefs